# Postgresql limit user to only functions and procedures

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am new to databases in general and I need some help with user privileges.  I created a desktop application in C# that uses npgsql to connect to my PostgreSQL database.  Every command to the database is either a function or a procedure.  I want to create a user for the database to use in my C# code that only has the right to execute those specific functions and procedures and nothing more.

I used the following code to create the user:

```
create user userdb with password 'blabla';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE test TO userdb;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE test FROM userdb;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM userdb;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public FROM userdb;
```

I then performed the following for each procedure and function:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION LoadEmails() TO userdb;
```

When I run any of the procedures or functions, I get an error 42501: permission denied for table emails.

Sample code for LoadEmails():

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LoadEmails()
RETURNS setof text AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT email FROM emails;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, functions run with the privileges of the user invoking the function. Specify `SECURITY DEFINER` to allow the function to use the privileges of the user that owns the function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LoadEmails()
RETURNS setof text
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT email FROM emails;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Does this pose any security threats?

Comment: That seemed to solve the problem for Functions.  How do I do this for Procedures?

Comment: Yes, [that can be a security problem](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/abusing-security-definer-functions/) if you don't do it right.

Comment: Do the same for procedures.

Comment: Thanks, @LaurenzAlbe. I had planned on posting a link to your article when I got back online. There are also risks associated with interactions between `SECURITY DEFINER` and row level security.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you folks for helping.  This solved my problem. I added security definer, set search path and revoked every other privilege.  Everything seems to be working.

Comment: @JohnH Well, then your example should set `search_path`.

Answer (score -1):

The error is because the user accessing the database does not have privilege to execute on "emails" table. Function itself requires additional privilege to execute query.

What you need to do is to grant permissions to the user. This can be done as:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE myTable TO myUser;
```

For Stored Procedures refer [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html).

Comment: This is exactly what you don’t want to do, you don’t want to give the user (direct) access to the tables. And there is no need for either, use security definer.